# Add JSON value in correct section

Tags: json, shell, jq

My json file 'veggies.json' as follows:

```
{"plants":
  {"veggies":
    [
      {"section":"TUBERS",
        "values":
          [
            {"tuber":"potato","type":"stem"}
          ]
      },
      {"section":"LEGUMES",
        "values":
          [
            {"legume":"beans"},
            {"legume":"peanuts"}
          ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to add another tuber "yam", which is of type "root" - this has to go under the section TUBERS.

I've just started off with JSON, and I have been breaking my head with all sorts of jq commands, but to not much avail.

I tried to read the value at values[0] with the following command, but I don't seem to be able to list anything:

```
jq -r "[.[] | select(.plants.veggies.section == \"TUBERS\") | .plants.veggies.values.tuber]" veggies.json
```

Essentially, I am trying to achieve this - if plants section is TUBERS, add tuber "yam" which is of type "root"

Can anybody please help me out?

Oh, and I am stuck with jq version 1.2, if that matters (backward compatibility and all that stuff).

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the [Complex assignments](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Complexassignments) section of the manual, it shows you exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
jq '(.plants.veggies[] | select(.section == "TUBERS") | .values) |= . + [{"type": "root", "tuber": "yam"}]' veggies.json
```

This runs a sub-filter: selecting the elements of the veggies array, finding the element with a matching section and yielding the values varray.  Then it appends the object to the values array.

This is essentially the same as the filters in your own answer with one key difference: because you don't actually filter anything out of the main input data, it will print out the entire JSON document (not just the modified portion).  I'm not sure if that's a benefit to you or not, but it makes it really easy to modify the document as a whole in a script.

(tested on jq 1.3)

Comment: Woah - you are right - your's prints out the entire document, while mine just printed the section I had modified - and what my code does - that's not good. I definitely do need the entire document. Thank you very much for your clarification.

Do you have resources/links where I can learn such types of stuff (the code that I had written has obviously been written with very little understanding of what was happening)

Comment: This functionality is explained in the [Complex Assignments](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Complexassignments) section of the documentation (all the way at the end).  It's not the clearest, IMO, that this is what it's showing but that's where I learned how to do it.  See the last example on that page.

(and don't forget to mark the check box next to this answer if you feel it resolved question :D )

Comment: Hey @0x783czar - I noticed that if I execute the same command multiple times, the code is getting added multiple times. Is there any way to do the "ifexists, edit, else add" routine to this logic?

Comment: A small simplification: instead of "|= . +", you can write "+=" here.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind - after some more head-cracking, I think I got it:

```
cat veggies.json | jq '.plants.veggies[] | select(.section == "TUBERS") | .values |= . + [{ "type": "root", "tuber": "yam" }]'
```

This seems to do what I want:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "type": "stem",
      "tuber": "potato"
    },
    {
      "tuber": "yam",
      "type": "root"
    }
  ],
  "section": "TUBERS"
}
```

If somebody can optimize this even further, I'd be very eager to learn that as well.