# Add JSON value uniquely in correct section using jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

This question is an extension to an earlier question I had asked earlier: [Add JSON value in correct section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729683/add-json-value-in-correct-section/25730853#25730853)

Essentially, I have a json file 'veggies.json' as follows:

```
{"plants":
  {"veggies":
    [
      {"section":"TUBERS",
        "values":
          [
            {"tuber":"potato","cookstyle":"fry"}
          ]
      },
      {"section":"LEGUMES",
        "values":
          [
            {"legume":"beans","cookstyle":"boil"},
            {"legume":"peanuts","cookstyle":"salted"}
          ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to add another tuber "yam", which can have cookstyle "boil" - this has to go under the section TUBERS, but uniquely. Meaning, I want to add this tuber only if it is not already there - if it already there, I just want to replace it with whatever "cookstyle" I am passing - it could be cookstyle:"mashed" as well.

From my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729683/add-json-value-in-correct-section/25730853#25730853), I already have this code using the 'jq' tool:

```
jq '(.plants.veggies[] | select(.section == "TUBERS") | .values) |= . + [{"cookstyle": "boil", "tuber": "yam"}]' veggies.json
```

However, this line of code keeps adding the same line multiple times under the TUBERS section - is there any way I can add it uniquely (hash like behaviour)

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Lakshminarayanan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3759959/lakshminarayanan-k)'s solution is very close.  If you don't want the duplicate yam if it's already in the array you can remove it with **unique**. E.g.

```
   (
       .plants.veggies[]
     | select(.section == "TUBERS")
     | .values

   ) |= (
          . + [ {"cookstyle": "boil", "tuber": "yam"} ]
          | unique
        )
```

Or perhaps consider putting the logic in a separate function so that it can be more easily managed if it gets complex. E.g.

```
def addyam:
     . + [ {"cookstyle": "boil", "tuber": "yam"} ]
   | unique
;

   (
       .plants.veggies[]
     | select(.section == "TUBERS")
     | .values

   ) |= addyam
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it *should* work, but it doesn't -- if there's no "yam", then the output is empty.

```
jq '
  if (.plants.veggies[] | select(.section == "TUBERS") | .values)[] | select(.tuber == "yam")
  then . 
  else (.plants.veggies[] | select(.section == "TUBERS") | .values) += [{"tuber":"yam", "cookstyle":"mashed"}]    
  end
' veggies.json
```

Comment: I [posted a reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25906604/3759959) as to how I finally did it (instead of overthinking it) - and it works for me - your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - turns out that I was overthinking this entire thing - maybe it is possible as a one-liner with jq itself, but since I have the liberty of working with shell, I simply just checked for whether "yam" is present, if not, add it, and if it does, edit it - like so:

```
IS_YAM_PRESENT=`jq '(.plants.veggies[] | select(.section == "TUBERS") | .values[] | select(.tuber == "yam") | .cookstyle)' veggies.json`
if [ -z ${IS_YAM_PRESENT} ]
then
    jq '(.plants.veggies[] | select(.section == "TUBERS") | .values) |= . + [{ "tuber": "yam", "cookstyle": "boiled" }]' veggies.json
else
    jq '(.plants.veggies[] | select(.section == "TUBERS") | .values[] | select(.tuber == "yam")) |= { "tuber": "yam", "cookstyle": "boiled" }' veggies.json
fi
```

As always, if anybody has a better more "refined" and "tighter" solution to this, I would be most happy to see it.

Cheers! :)